# Comparing two dictionaries of lists of tuples in order to calculate F-score

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Python noob here.

I have two dictionaries of lists of tuples: `my_gold_mentions`, which includes my gold data, and `my_coref`, which includes automatically generated data.

Both dictionaries look like this:

```
{'Anakin': [(6532, 6538),
            (6590, 6592),
            (6673, 6675)],
 'He': [(3600, 3602),
        (3609, 3612)],...}  #  etc.
```

I am trying to calculate the **F score** by comparing the tuples of the automatically generated dictionary with the gold data one's.

If there's a match for a tuple, then I'd like to check if both of those matched tuples have the same key, in this case: a shared character's name, e.g. `'Anakin'`.

If so: then add 1 to the **True Positives** count.

If the keys are not similar, yet the automatically generated key exists in the gold data dictionary as a key in general (in this case: another character than `'Anakin'`), then I should consider it to be *both* a **False Negative** and **False Positive**.

Lastly, if the key doesn't exist at all in the gold data dictionary, then consider it only a **False Negative**.

So far I have tried this:

```
TP = 0
FP = 0
FN = 0
for gold_key, gold_value in my_gold_mentions:
    for auto_key, auto_value in my_coref:
        if auto_value == gold_value:
            if auto_key == gold_key:
                TP += 1
            elif auto_key != gold_key and auto_key in my_gold_mentions:
                FN += 1
                FP += 1
        else:
            FN += 1
```

Which doesn't look very effective, as I'm getting a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

I'm not sure how to compare two dictionaries of lists of tuples.

Any ideas on how to improve the code above to achieve that goal?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: to iterate over key:values, you want `dict.items()`

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should probably learn to debug yourself. Almost all of the question is not relevant to the problem, it's a pure Python quesiton. Try to do `for x, y in {"a": 1, "b": 2}: pass` and you will get the same problem. To see why, run `for thing in {"a": 1, "b": 2}: print(thing)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive, `O(n^2)` solution, would be to loop through all the tuples in all the lists (dictionary values) of the randomly generated data and check if those tuples match any of the tuples in any of the lists of the gold data. This would be inefficient for a large data set, as, worse case with no-matches, you need to loop through all the gold-data data tuples *for each* tuple in the randomised tuples.

A faster method would be to use a data-structure which allows average-case `O(1)` lookup (as opposed to the `O(n)` lookup in a list). The types Python supports are `dictionary` and `set`.

A `set` is a collection of items, where each item would generally hold one piece of data. A `dictionary` is more appropriate when there are two linked pieces of data. Here, you do have two linked/related items, namely the name and the tuples.

Since it is the tuples that you will be constantly checking for presence in the dictionary, it would only be efficient if you were to store them in the following format as you can then query for any tuple very efficiently. In addition, when you do find a tuple and want to know its name, you can find that straight away too.

```
{(123,456):'some_name',
 (234,567):'another_name')}
```

---

To convert your `my_gold_mentions` dictionary to the format I suggest, you could use this dictionary-comprehension:

```
{tup:name for name, tups in my_gold_mentions.items() for tup in tups}
```

which gives:

```
{(6532, 6538): 'Anakin',
 (6590, 6592): 'Anakin',
 (6673, 6675): 'Anakin',
 (3600, 3602): 'He',
 (3609, 3612): 'He'}
```

---

Now that you have created a nicer data structure (let's call this `tup_gold_mentions`), you can complete the task efficiently:

```
TP = FN = FP = 0
for name, tups in my_coref.items():
    for tup in tups:
        if tup in tup_gold_mentions:
            if name == tup_gold_mentions[tup]:
                TP += 1
            else:
                FN += 1
                FP += 1
        else:
            FN += 1
```

---

Which, with the `my_coref` as:

```
{'Anakin': [(6532, 6538),
            (123, 45)],
 'Bob': [(3600, 3602)],
 'Jim': [(12, 34)]}
```

gives the right results:

```
>>> TP
1
>>> FP
1
>>> FN
3
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It's extremely helpful and informative. Sadly, i'm getting an `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'` for the line `for name, tups in my_coref.items():`.

Comment: have you defined `my_coref` as a dictionary in the format that I showed underneath the code?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I had a little mistake somewhere that I didn't notice. It works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Waldkamel No problem. Please accept then! (grey--> green tick next to this answer)

Answer (score 1):

Change `my_gold_mentions` and `my_coref` to `my_gold_mentions.items()` and `my_coref.items()` this will allow you access the `keys` and `values` you are trying to compare

```
for gold_key, gold_value in my_gold_mentions.items():
    for auto_key, auto_value in my_coref.items():
```